# web-mode doesn't give correct indentation

Tags: indentation, web-mode

I have the following lines activated:

```
(setq indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq tab-width 1)
(setq web-mode-markup-indent-offset 1)
(setq web-mode-css-indent-offset 1)
(setq web-mode-code-indent-offset 1)
```

but when I do `C-x h` then `indent-region`, it does indent it with 4 spaces everywhere, when I do tab on a line, it sets line indentation to 2 spaces(relevant to other lines). What am I doing wrong? I also didn't find anything useful in `M-x customize`

thanks

Comment: What does `M-: (featurep 'web-mode) RET` tell you? What does `M-: major mode RET` (run in the HTML file buffer) tell you?

Comment: NickD the first one is `t` the second one is `major-mode` gave me `web-mode`

Comment: What does `C-h v indent-line-function` say?

Comment: It says: 
```
indent-line-function is a variable defined in ‘indent.el’.

Its value is ‘web-mode-indent-line’
Local in buffer checkout.html; global value is indent-relative

(description)...
```

Comment: Not sure why you are getting this. I cannot reproduce it with a  minimal init file and a minimal HTML file - see my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

With a minimal init file `foo.el` like this:

```el
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.config/emacs/elpa/web-mode-17.3.17/")

(require 'web-mode)

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.html\\'" . web-mode))

(setq indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq tab-width 1)
(setq web-mode-markup-indent-offset 1)
(setq web-mode-css-indent-offset 1)
(setq web-mode-code-indent-offset 1)
```

a minimal HTML file `foo.html` like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" >
<head>
<title>Title</title>
  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/base.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/base.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8" name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE" />
</head>
<body class="">
Body
</body>
</html>
```

and starting emacs like this:

```sh
emacs -Q -l foo.el foo.html
```

indenting either with `C-x h C-M-\` or with TABs on each line gives me this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" >
 <head>
  <title>Title</title>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/base.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/base.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8" name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE" />
 </head>
 <body class="">
  Body
 </body>
</html>
```

All I can suggest is that the rest of your init file is causing the problem, so maybe try with `-Q` and a minimal init as above (but adjust the `load-path` appropriately for your setup).

Answer (score 0):

One better-than-nothing solution would be:
`C-x h M-: (indent-region-line-by-line (region-beginning) (region-end)) RET`

At least it works for me with those variables( `(setq web-mode-code-indent-offset 1)` )